# Command line works in terminal but not in a variable under bash

Tags: terminal, bash

The following command line works both in Terminal and when called in a bash script:

```
cd /home/user/Schreibtisch/Tor_FF/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/ && TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 ./start-tor-browser --allow-remote
```

However, when I put the command line in bash into a variable, I get an error message when using the variable.

```
variable="cd /home/user/Schreibtisch/Tor_FF/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/ && TOR_FORCE_NET_CONFIG=0 ./start-tor-browser --allow-remote"

$variable
```

Errormessage:

```
cd: Too many arguments.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run it with `eval $variable`, otherwise everything after `cd` is passed as arguments to `cd`.